# How do I escape backslashes and forward slashes in Neo4J Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When I run,

```
MATCH (p:person {id:'1'}), (a:Address {street:"11\34, Wall street"})RETURN p, a;
```

> Invalid input 'S': expected '\', ''', '"', 'b', 'f', 'n', 'r', 't', '_', '%', UTF16 or UTF32

How do I handle `\` and `/` special characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use double quotes `"` for a string, use single quotes `'` and use double slash `\\` to insert single backward slash `\`. The `\` will escape the character after it (like in C).

```
MATCH (p:person {id:'1'}), (a:Address {street:'11\\34, Wall street'})RETURN p, a;
```

Comment: Actually, you can use either single or double quotes.